# how to save time with AM or PM included in it?

Tags: php, datetime

i'm working on project where i'm doing this piece of code

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');
$login_time=>date('h:i:s');
```

now is there anyway i can include AM/PM value in my database? or i'm missing any step to do that :|

Comment: [Did you read this](http://au1.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)?

Comment: try to save it as unix timestamp in your database then in your php when you fetch it format it as date('h:i:s A'), do not store it in your database as varchar.

Comment: you can also format when retrieving from the db using DATE_FORMAT() (assuming mysql)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save with AM or PM, based on your given code , it should be written with 'A' inside date function like this:

```
  date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');
  $login_time=>date('h:i:s A');
```

A  = Uppercase Ante meridiem and Post meridiem.

Read more about date function [here.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Comment: you should not store AM\PM in the db, you should store as a 24hour date and format on dispalay\extraction

Answer (score 0):

Though I'd recommend using the database to format your date, it is also possible using the [PHP Date function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php). To wit:

```
$login_time_as_string = date ("h:i:s A", $login_time);
```

If you need more assistance, do leave a comment.